# Hiding certain form details to particular user

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

Can i design my form in such a way that can hide certain details to particular user?or visible only to reviewer side and not visible for client user

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to hide certain fields from a particular category of members. In the open-source project of [formsflow.ai](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai), they are giving 2 sample forms
FOI and New business Licence in that itself they are using this feature. In that, the reviewer section of the FOI form is available only at the reviewer side and I will attach the code for the same here
[image: Reference]

```
const UserDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UserDetails"))
const groups = UserDetails["groups"]

if(groups.includes("/formsflow/formsflow-reviewer") && data.applicationStatus==="New") {
  show = true;
}
else {
show = false;
}
```

Also, you can design the form as per your requirements by giving conditions while designing the form